# Xp Pen Artist Pro 15.6 Tablet not working after installing Pentablet Driver XP-Pen on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: command-line, 18.04, drivers, tablet

I installed the Pentablet Driver via Terminal, opening Terminal in the folder with the extracted file typing  `sudo ./Pentablet_Driver.sh` in. 
after enter the window setting of the driver will open, but after I closed it my tablet and stylus weren't working anymore. Now it only works when I open terminal and type in the code, while the driver window is open I can use my tablet. How do I undo this? Because creating a desktop.file also doesn't work.

The following is what I typed into the text editor and saved under ~/.local/share/applications

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY sh -c /home/je/Linux_Pentablet_V1.2.13.1/Pentablet_Driver.sh
MimeType=application/x-your-mime-type;
Icon=/home/je/xp-pen.png
X-DocPath=
Terminal=false
Name=XP-Pen
GenericName=XP-Pen
Comment=xp-pen driver for xp-pen pad and pen
Categories=Graphics;2DGraphics;RasterGraphics;Utility;
```

clicking on the app in my applications, it asks for my password and after typing it in nothing happens. 
I'm no expert, but I did something wrong and I don't know what. 
Hopefully someone is able to help me

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I assume there's still no solution yet?

Comment: Apparently the table only works properly while the script is running, presumably because of the screen map. While this doesn't directly answer your question (of undoing the affect), check out this answer on how to autostart it with your session: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243965/xp-pen-artist-pro-15-6-tablet-not-working-after-installing-pentablet-driver-xp-p